# Crystal Reports 10 - How to print 2 different labels from 1 report (1x1)

Tags: label, crystal-reports-10

I need to create a Crystal Report for a label printer. The label printer is Brother QL-570 with width 1-1/7" & length (height) 1.15 & feed (gap I think) of .12... essentially 1x1. But I want 2 labels per print with different things on each. Can this be done in a single report?

I've tried the Section Export and Layout - doubling the size and adding another sub-Details section. I get an error "reports page header/footer too large" even though those sections are suppressed.